# Unity freezes while training ML agents

Tags: ubuntu-unity

I am trying to train ball example in Unity on Mac, after running `mlagents-learn` command in terminal, and pressing play in scene Unity just freezes there. I also tried waiting few hours if Unity will eventually respond, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
mlagents-learn config/trainer_config.yaml --run-id=SomeTest1 --train
```

Running on following

1. Python3.6.0
2. PIP 19.1.1

Comment: Do you see a change in system utilization? Does it have some kind of log? DO you run it standalone or from within the Unity Editor? [This](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-with-Balance-Ball.md) would suggest there are files being created that would allow you to track whenever it's working?

Comment: System utilization is minimal from unity, it is about 5%. I tried running the test from the executable as well and executable also stops responding once I run training. Tensorflow board does not contain any data either.